# Is there an issue with double adding events on an element?

Tags: jquery

Lets say I add a `.submit()` event to a `<form>`. Will there be a problem if I add the same `.submit()` event to the same `<form>` multiple times?

To clarify, I have a function that initialize and populates the `<form>` and creates the `.submit()` event. After the `<form>` is submitted I have to re-initialze and re-populate the `<form>`. The easy way would be to call the same function that does this but also creates the `.submit()` event on the same `<form>` - this really isn't necessary but having one function that does both seem more readable.

Comment: Yes that's a problem. Every event you attach will be executed - even the duplicates. From what you describe it sounds like you just need to use a single delegated event handler to save you having to worry about attaching any events when you create the new `form` element. Seeing a sample of your code would help give you a reliable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery to add the handler repeatedly, it will be added repeatedly and thus called repeatedly when the event occurs (but keep reading). Example:

```js
var target = $("#target");
target.on("click", handler);
target.on("click", handler);
target.on("click", handler);

function handler() {
  console.log("handler called");
}
```

```html
<div id="target">click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The simple thing to do in that case is mark the element you've added the handler to in some way so you know whether to add it:

```
var form = $("....");
if (!form.hasClass("has-handler")) {
    form.on("submit", handler).addClass("has-handler");
}
```

---

Note: The above isn't true of the DOM, however, provided you use the **same** function:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
target.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
target.addEventListener("click", handler, false);

function handler() {
  console.log("handler called");
}
```

```html
<div id="target">click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very good idea to mark the element. I will do that. But shouldn't you use the data attribute instead of the class attribute to do things like this? In jQuery use .data() and .removeData()?

Comment: @Espen: It's totally up to you. On the one hand, adding a class you don't use for styling or selecting the element is slightly misusing it. On the other hand, it's fairly harmless (doesn't cost you in terms of CSS application) and simple. Note, though, that `data` and `removeData` **don't** use a `data-*` attribute (which, in this case, is good). They use jQuery's internal data cache for the element, which is only *initialized* from `data-*` attributes. Neither `data` nor `removeData` ever modifies a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: I see. It then seem like a good idea to use jQuery's .data() for speed and style :-)